# How to implement blocking ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I need to implement blocking `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

This is a very crucial requirement in our enterprise application.

It would do something like if `ThreadPoolExecutor.submit()` or `ThreadPoolExecutor.execute()` method blocks until a thread gets freed up for picking up a new task.

But in current implementation `ThreadPoolExecutor.submit()` and `ThreadPoolExecutor.execute()` methods throw RejectedExecutionException exception if all pooled threads get busy.

For example following code throws `RejectedExecutionException`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class BlockingTPE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayBlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(3);
        ThreadPoolExecutor tpExe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 3, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);
        int numJobs = 50;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numJobs; i++) {
            try {
                tpExe.submit(new WorkerThread(i));
                System.out.println("Added#" + (i));
            } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
    int jobId;

    public WorkerThread(int jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception excep) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be helpful, utilize a semaphore -> http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_semaphore2.shtml

Comment: You can chose cached queue, it will grow on demand.
See example  : http://farenda.com/java/java-cached-thread-pool/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the javadoc of `ThreadPoolExecutor` states:

> Creates a new ThreadPoolExecutor with the given initial parameters and
>   default thread factory and rejected execution handler.

The rejected executor handler is an instance of `AbortPolicy` which will be called if the queue does not accept another task. The behavior as of the javadoc:

> Always throws RejectedExecutionException.

Hence the blocking queue does not have any effect for you. I changed your code this way and it runs without any issues:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            1, 3, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue(3));
    try {
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        int numJobs = 50;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numJobs; i++) {
            try {
                executor.submit(new WorkerThread(i));
                System.out.println("Added#" + (i));
            } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

The decision you have to make is:

- use an unbound queue to support all delayed tasks. For example `LinkedBlockingQueue`.
- use a bound queue and let the current thread execute the task which does not fit into the full queue. For example see the code I posted along my answer.
- discard tasks if the bounded queue is full. For example use `ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy` as rejected execution handler.